# Different formats of return type in Python 3

Tags: types, python-3.9

Suppose we have user defined datatype `class Node`. There are two functions `funcA` and `funcB`.
Both the functions accept a single parameter of type `Node`. After some processing, they return a single value of type `Node`. However, the return type of `funcA` is `Node` which is obvious but `funcB` also returns a value of type `Node` that is expressed as `"Node"`.

How does type hinting in Python3 understand the difference between type `Node` and string `"Node"`?

```
def funcA (input_node:Node) -> Node
 ..

def funcA (input_node:Node) -> "Node"
 ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both work. Sometimes the type is a forward reference, which would not compile. In that case, enclosing the type in quotes allows the forward reference.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references

Comment: "Sometimes the type is a forward reference" .. do you have an example?

Comment: Yes, the link I provided, to PEP 484, has examples. `'Tree'` vs `Tree`.